# Windy Add tooltip below marker

Tags: tooltip, marker

I have a marker on my Windy map (https://www.windy.com) and trying to put a tooltip or text below the marker that will be always visible (irrespective if click or not on the marker).

Below is my JS:

```
// MARKER of Convoy on the Map
const icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'http://imap.klickitatcounty.org/img/marker-icon-blue.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [13, 41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -25],
});

// ...MARKER of Convoy Create...
const marker = L.marker([latitude,longitude], {
    icon: icon,
});

// ...MARKER add to maps...
marker.addTo(maps);

// ...MARKER attach a popup to it with some content:
marker.bindPopup(
    '<h2>0hrs</h2><a ', {
    className: 'my-popup'
}).openPopup();
```

and also my CSS:

```
.my-popup img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

.my-popup h2 {
    color: black;
}
```

I am not an expert, so if anyone can assist I would appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: So to clarify, you want a caption to pop-up along with the marker?